# spark steaming with kafka, cannot receive all data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

In my spark streaming program, I try to receive data from kafka. In kafka producer, I send 1 million messages, but in the spark streaming, I cannot receive all the messages. It'll always loss some messages.
I start kafka-server with the default config.
Here is my producer's code:

```
val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
for (i <- 1 to loop_times.toInt) {
   var cnt = 0
   while (cnt < record_count.toInt) {
        val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, null, "aaa")
        producer.send(message)
        cnt += 1
        if (cnt % 10000 == 0)
            println(s"send $cnt records")
    }
}
producer.close()
```

and here is my spark streaming code(this code is in spark's example):

```
object KafkaWordCount {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
if (args.length < 4) {
  System.err.println("Usage: KafkaWordCount <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads>")
  System.exit(1)
}

StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels()

val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads) = args
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1L))
  .reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Minutes(10), Seconds(2), 2)
wordCounts.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

My spark's version is 1.6 and kafka's is 0.8.2.1

Comment: How do you know that messages are lost?

Comment: What you could do is add number to each message, so you can see which ones are dropped (from beginning, somewhere from the middle or from the end). So don't reduce, just print out the numbers and then report back the findings. I suspect that your `window` filters out messages either from the beginning or the end and that you'll see all messages if you don't `reduce`.

Comment: @Sumit, I sum the total number of words, and every time I cannot get the expected answer 1000,000

Comment: @MarkoBonaci Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try it out!